# neo4j property name, node name and edge name length

Tags: neo4j

If concerned with the RAM footprint of a neo4j graph database should the model be designed to contain intentionally short property names, node names and edge names in the case where there may be millions of these items in order to save space or does name node/property/edge length not impact RAM footprint - is there just one copy of the name or is it repeated in each node/edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j is using Lucene. 
So, from old memories, there is nothing to worry about this.

My naming advice is keep them clear. 
Make them long enough to understand them upon reading.

Graph 'models' tends to go more complicated with project evolutions too.
Be kind with the future you.